# RMarkdown size directives ignored for in-document chunk output when using html_notebook_output_html or kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, rnotebook

In an r notebook viewed in RStudio, I can have the following yaml, setup, r chunk, and text:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_notebook: 
    fig_height: 2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height=2, fig.width=2, out.height=2, out.width=2)
```

```{r fig.height=2, fig.width=2, out.height=2, out.width=2}

rmarkdown::html_notebook_output_html(
  "<div style='border:1px solid red'>hello</div>"
)

```
goodbye
````

Note the variety of ways I'm trying to establish the height for the html object.  For the .nb.html file, this outputs just fine.  'Goodbye' is right after a red bordered 'hello'.

However, for the in-document output that follows immediately after the code chunk, the output is quite tall (I believe the default is 7 inches, and that's about what it seems to be), and certainly outsizes its contents.  The size directives (fig.height, out.height) are ignored.

Is there a more appropriate way to set the size?

[image: rnotebook chunk output]

I ran into the issue when using kable:

````
```{r fig.height=2, fig.width=2, out.height=2, out.width=2}

knitr::kable(data.frame(col1 = c('hello')), 'html')

```
````

Though I don't think it's a kable issue, based on the first example, I believe it's an rmarkdown issue.

Comment: Looks like an RStudio issue (you're viewing it there, right?), not an rmarkdown issue.

Comment: @user2554330, I edited to add the RStudio tag and changed first sentence to reflect that I'm viewing this in RStudio.  Thanks.